# Output of interactive program on sublime 3 console

Tags: c, mingw, sublimetext3

I am learning to write C program using sublime3 text editor and i have two different sublime builds for it 
This build outputs its execution on CMD console ;

```
> {
"cmd": ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k",  "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true
}
```

while the other build outputs its execution on the sublime console

```
> {
"cmd": ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",


"variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["gcc","${file}", "-o", "$file_base_name", "&&", "$file_path/$file_base_name"],
            "shell":true
        }
    ]
}
```

I prefer the second build but it only works when you use it to run non interactive program e.g `"Hello world"` program and it gives me error message when I use it to run a simple interactive program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>


// variable declaration;

int main()
{   
    float a,b,sum;

    printf("Enter value of a\n");
    // for float u use "f" instead of d
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter value of b\n");   
    scanf("%f",&b);
    sum=a+b;
    printf("The sum of %f and %f = %f\n",a,b,sum);

    return 0;
}
```

error message:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot open output file addition.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status [Finished in 0.3s]

I want to know if i can execute interactive programs on sublime console or I need to do something about my sublime build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: No, you can't run an interactive program within Sublime (and interact with it).

That error message from the linker is telling you that it wants to create/modify the file `addition.exe` but it is not allowed to do so because the operating system (in this case windows) told it that it can't.

The underlying reason for that is that windows won't let you delete/modify a file that is currently in use, which in this case means it's running right now.

To get to the nub of your problem, it's not possible to run an interactive program directly within sublime; or rather, you can run such a program but there is no connection made between input in the console and the program you're running.

This means that when you run the program you can't interact with it, but it's still sitting there running waiting for you to enter something. Then when you modify the code and try to build and run it again, you get the error you see here because the executable is still running and can't be modified. In this case you can cancel the build to stop the running program.

In order to run a program like this you need to run it outside of Sublime so that you can interact with it (or use a build system that does this for you such as your first example).

It is also possible to use the [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) package to construct a build system that is interactive. The README includes documentation on how to do this, including a link to a tutorial video that outlines the process.